# Executing stored procedure from Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having a procedure which simply returns data from multiple tables. I'm trying to execute this procedure from EF as follows

```
await _context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(command).ToListAsync();
```

Firstly, I have created a model class with property names to match the columns returned by the SP. Removed some properties for simplification,

```
public partial class Inventory
{
    public string? location { get; set; }

    public string? Warehouse { get; set; }

    public string? Company { get; set; }

    public string? Item { get; set; }
}
```

secondly, Added DbSet property to the context class

```
public virtual DbSet<Inventory> Inventorys { get; set; }
```

Then, I'm trying to call **MapToStoredProcedures** on entity **Inventory**.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>().MapToStoredProcedures();
```

But, MapToStoredProcedures() is not recognized. I've verified that EF 7 packages are referenced by the project. What Am I missing here?

Comment: MapToStoredProcedures is for Entity Framework 6 classic, not for EF Core. Have a look a EF Core Power Tools for simple stored prcedure mapping

Comment: @ErikEJ Thank you, I will check on that.

Comment: @ErikEJ I went through your post at https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/08/03/ef-core-call-stored-procedures-out-parameters.html and was able to get it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps in https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/08/03/ef-core-call-stored-procedures-out-parameters.html and was able to get it working.